# Why does my printf not print the elements of my array?

Tags: arrays, c, bubble-sort

As a practice task I have tried implementing the bubble sort algorithm using the C programming language. The following is my code:

```
int main() {
    int arr[5];
    int i, j;
    int n = sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(arr);
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }

    printf("Array before ordering:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Array after ordering:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    system("PAUSE");
    exit(0);
}
```

As you can see I have two loops to print out the array, one to print out the initial array and one to print it out after ordering it. Yet this is the output:

**Array before ordering:**

**Array after ordering:**

**Press any key to continue . . .**

For some reason i cannot seem to output the elements of the array. I have tried running it on Visual Studio and CLion. Can anyone see what is wrong here?

Comment: `int n = sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(arr);` - it should be the other way around.

Comment: `int n = sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(arr);` is (probably) `int n = 4 / 20;` is `int n = 0;`

Comment: You should learn how to run your program in a debugger. Watching your variables while stepping through the code should reveal the problem within seconds.

Answer (score 2):

`int n = sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(arr);`

This should be the other way around. i.e. `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`

If you want to debug this, try printing n.